# Grep and run command in every folder where a file contained a match

Tags: grep, find, command

I'm looking for an elegant way to execute a command in every folder where grep has found a match in a file. Much like `find`'s `-execdir` flag, except that find only searches folder/file names, but not their content.

Currently, I'm using something like

```
grep -r "pattern" --include=\*.out -l | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd `dirname "$0"` && some_script.sh'
```

Is there a more direct way? Something like `grep ... -execdir`?

Comment: Does that suit your needs? http://www.valleyprogramming.com/blog/linux-find-grep-commands-exec-combine-search

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://serverfault.com/a/292758/124400

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? This will run  `some_script.sh` multiple times in the same directory if there's more than one file content matching the pattern  inside that directory. Is that what you actually want ?

Answer (score 4):

`find` can run `grep`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.out' \
    -exec grep -q -e 'pattern' {} \; \
    -execdir somescript.sh \;
```

This would find the pathname of any regular file whose name ends in `.out`. For each found pathname, it would use `grep` to determine whether the pattern matches any line in the file.  If it does, `-execdir` is used to execute `somescript.sh` with the directory of the found file as its working directory.

Note that `somescript.sh` needs to be available somewhere in `$PATH` for this to work and that the script would be executed once for each file that is found, not once for each directory that contains a `.out` file with a match.

To only execute the script once in each directory that contains a `.out` file with a match:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        if grep -q -e "pattern" "$dirpath"/*.out 2>/dev/null; then
            ( cd "$dirpath" && exec somescript.sh )
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This uses `find` to look for directories rather than for files.  For batches of directories found, a short in-line shell script is executed.  the shell script tries to match the pattern against all `.out` files in each directory (excluding hidden ones, while `find` would still look into hidden directories), and if any file matches, a subshell is started in which the working directory is changed and the `somescript.sh` script is executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the script only once for each directory that contains at least one matching `out` file, and avoid running one `grep` per file, you could do:

```
P="pattern" find . -name '*.out' -type f -exec gawk '
  BEGINFILE {
    dir = FILENAME; sub("/[^/]*$", "", dir)
    if (dir in found) nextfile
  }
  $0 ~ ENVIRON["P"] {
    printf "%s\0", dir
    found[dir]
    nextfile
  }' {} + | xargs -r0 sh -c '
    for dir do
      (cd "$dir" && exec somescript.sh)
    done' sh
```

That would run as few processes as possible and `gawk` would read as few files (and as little of each file) as possible.

It assumes GNU `xargs` or compatible and that the names of the files don't contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale.

With one GNU `grep` invocation (and GNU `dirname`, `sort`, `xargs`):

```
grep -rlZ --include='*.out' pattern . |
  xargs -r0 dirname -z |
  sort -zu |
  xargs -r0 sh -c '
    for dir do
      (cd "$dir" && exec somescript.sh)
    done' sh
```

Contrary to the previous solution, that would look in all `out` files even those in directories where a matching files has already been found. As GNU `grep` is more efficient at grepping than `gawk`, it might still be more efficient depending on the amount of superfluous data it would end up grepping into.